# Selenium: This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server in IE8 to IE11

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run a selenium test in IE and running into issue where this message "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server" appears and nothing happens after that.

Tests run successfully in chrome and firefox but issue is only with IE.
I tried all the solutions given in previous threads like [This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979283/this-is-the-initial-start-page-for-the-webdriver-server) but doesn't help.

Can someone help me with this issue.

Comment: It's *almost* 2018, let internet explorer [die](http://www.vocativ.com/270200/death-of-internet-explorer/index.html) [already](http://fortune.com/2016/01/12/internet-explorer-death/).

Comment: Seeing `This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server` denotes that the initialization of `WebDriver` & `Web Browser`  is perfecto. Now you need to get your hands dirty with some code.

Comment: @DebanjanB I  already have code to access some page which works fine for firefox and chrome but for IE somehow it doesn't move ahead of Initial start page. Last line of code its stuck at is " webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);" I have some code to manage window size first and then hit a request.

Comment: Can you share your code trial and relevant `HTML` please?